# In pandas Dataframe with multiindex how can I filter by order?

Tags: python, pandas

Assume the following dataframe

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> L = [(1,'A',9,9), (1,'C',8,8), (1,'D',4,5),(2,'H',7,7),(2,'L',5,5)]
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(L).set_index([0,1])
>>> df
     2  3
0 1      
1 A  9  9
  C  8  8
  D  4  5
2 H  7  7
  L  5  5
```

I want to filter the rows in the nth position of level 1 of the multiindex, i.e. filtering the first

```
     2  3
0 1      
1 A  9  9
2 H  7  7
```

or filtering the third

```
     2  3
0 1      
1 D  4  5
```

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can filter rows with the help of [`GroupBy.nth`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.nth.html) after performing grouping on the first level of the multi-index `DF`. Since `n` follows the 0-based indexing approach, you need to provide the values appropriately to it as shown:

1) To select the first row grouped per `level=0`:

```
df.groupby(level=0, as_index=False).nth(0)
```

[image]

2) To select the third row grouped per `level=0`:

```
df.groupby(level=0, as_index=False).nth(2)
```

[image]

Comment: This is a really neat solution.